# How to download weka source code and use it into netbeans

Tags: weka

I want to download source code for `weka 3.6` and use it on `netbeans` to add some  modifications on `Apriori algorithm`. I have been searching on Google but I didn't find any thing which can help me to do that.

Comment: Grab all historical and current versions of Weka from here (all versions have weka-src.jar included): http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/

Answer (score 0):

You can find it on [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/). If you are looking for the jar, you can find it [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/w/Downloadwekasrcjar.htm) or on Subversion (follow [weka.wikispace instructions](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Subversion))

Also, if you installed Weka, in the installation folder there should be a jar called weka-src.jar